# Need query for this

Tags: sql-server

```
table A
Id   Name
---  -----
1     abc
2     bc
3     lm
5     vm
6     ops

Table B
Id    name
---   ------
1     abcd
2     bc
4     hr
```

I need a select query which returns output as follows

```
ID   Name   status
---  ----   -------
1    abcd   Name changed
2    bc     No change
3    lm     Not in table B
4    hr     not in table A
5    vm     not in table B
6    ops    not in table B
```

Comment: What did you try? What does not work? Why should we do your work? On SO you are supp0osed to show what you tried and get helped, see: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow (SO). SO isn't a free coding service, it's a website for asking **specific** questions regarding coding problems you're facing. When asking, it's important to show what you've already tried (don't just state "I tried" or "I used a `JOIN`" without evidence). Tell us the problems you had, such as errors, or the data that was missing, or why the behaviour wasn't right. Consider having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Show us some sample code so we can see what you tried and also what you got as a result from that query.

Answer (score 0):

One, not very nice, solution could be using `CASE` and `FULL JOIN`

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN A.name != B.name THEN 'Name changed' ELSE
      CASE WHEN A.name = B.name THEN 'No change' ELSE
          CASE WHEN A.name is null THEN 'Not in table A' ELSE
              CASE WHEN B.name is null THEN 'Not in table B' ELSE
              END
          END
      END
  END status
FROM A
FULL JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
```

Comment: You kind of just gave them the answer when they didn't really show us any of their own work or attempts.

Comment: So am I, but I like to wait to see some actual attempt before just giving answers away. Otherwise anyone can ask questions and just be like, 'here is a task, do it for me, I haven't tried it myself but I'm sure one of you will do it'.

Comment: Just giving people answers doesn't always help them. When you see someone asking a homework like question (I'm not saying this one is), for example, the worst thing you can do is give them the answer. Simply giving people an answer doesn't help them learn; especially if they haven't tried themselves. This is why questions with no attemptsoften get few answers, and receive comments asking for their attempts. Volunteers can understand the problem far better that way, and sometimes it can be as simple as a typograhpical error.